# how do I change my username on parse.com?

Tags: email, parse-platform, account

I created an account on parse.com several months ago using my email address as the username. My email address has changed but I can't find how to change the email address that I use to login to parse.com.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there is no way to do this (and I'll have you know that I put a lot of research into it).
I know this is an unorthodox answer but I just made a new account and migrated my stuff over there. (as I didn't have any important data which I couldn't afford to lose this was no problem, although I don't know how important it is for you to keep your current database).
Maybe you find a way to migrate your data but I don't think you can change the email adress via a feature implemented by the 'parse.com' team.

Sorry for the disappointing answer

Answer (score 1):

there you go, also had to search for it: There is an blue "Update" Button.

[Edit account page](https://www.parse.com/account/edit)